# Call method on many objects in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I wanted to use concurrency in Python for the first time. So I started reading a lot about Python concurreny (GIL, threads vs processes, multiprocessing vs concurrent.futures vs ...) and seen a lot of **convoluted** examples. Even in examples using the high level concurrent.futures library.

So I decided to just start trying stuff and was surprised with the very, very simple code I ended up with:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class WebHostChecker(object):
    def __init__(self, websites):
        self.webhosts = []
        for website in websites:
            self.webhosts.append(WebHost(website))

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.webhosts)

    def check_all(self):
        # sequential:
        #for webhost in self:
        #    webhost.check()
        # threaded:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            executor.map(lambda webhost: webhost.check(), self.webhosts)


class WebHost(object):
    def __init__(self, hostname):
        self.hostname = hostname

    def check(self):
        print("Checking {}".format(self.hostname))
        self.check_dns() # only modifies internal state, i.e.: sets self.dns
        self.check_http() # only modifies internal status, i.e.: sets self.http
```

Using the classes looks like this:

```
webhostchecker = WebHostChecker(["urla.com", "urlb.com"])
webhostchecker.check_all() # -> this calls .check() on all WebHost instances in parallel
```

The relevant multiprocessing/threading code is **only 3 lines**. I barely had to modify my existing code (which I hoped to be able to do when first starting to write the code for sequential execution, but started to doubt after reading the many examples online).

And... it **works**! :)

It perfectly distributes the IO-waiting among multiple threads and runs in less than 1/3 of the time of the original program.

So, now, my question(s):

- What am I missing here?
- Could I implement this differently? (Should I?)
- Why are other examples so convoluted? (Although I must say I couldn't find an exact example doing a method call on multiple objects)
- Will this code get me in trouble when I expand my program with features/code I cannot predict right now?
- I think I already know of one potential problem and it would be nice if someone can confirm my reasoning: if WebHost.check() also becomes CPU bound I won't be able to swap ThreadPoolExecutor for ProcessPoolExecutor. Because every process will get cloned versions of the WebHost instances? And I would have to code something to sync those cloned instances back to the original?

Any insights/comments/remarks/improvements/... that can bring me to greater understanding will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Way to broad, sorry. Threading makes sense in this application, as may multiprocessing. Unless you raise an explicit issue, it's tough to say what might go wrong specifically.

Comment: @roganjosh: I see your point. But maybe at the very least this code can server as an example for others wanting to do the very simple task of calling a method on multiple objects in parallel? In that case: do you see any issues with it? How would you have implemented this?

Comment: I really couldn't say. You've given code that apparently meets your issue. It really is too broad a topic; perhaps more so than you currently acknowledge. I'm not gonna throw speculation about

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'll add my own first gotcha:

If webhost.check() raises an Exception, then the thread just ends and self.dns and/or self.http might NOT have been set. However, with the current code, you won't see the Exception, UNLESS you also access the executor.map() results! Leaving me wondering why some objects raised AttributeErrors after running check_all() :)

This can easily be fixed by just evaluating every result (which is always None, cause I'm not letting .check() return anything). You can do it after all threads have run or during. I choose to let Exceptions be raised during (ie: within the with statement), so the program stops at the first unexpected error:

```
def check_all(self):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        # this alone works, but does not raise any exceptions from the threads:
        #executor.map(lambda webhost: webhost.check(), self.webhosts)
        for i in executor.map(lambda webhost: webhost.check(), self.webhosts):
            pass
```

I guess I could also use list(executor.map(lambda webhost: webhost.check(), self.webhosts)) but that would unnecessarily use up memory.